# How to iterate over a list of strings sent from a controller to a jsp

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I invoke the "addObject" of a ModelAndView like so: `modelAndView.addObject("userNames", userNames);`  The second argument is an ArrayList of strings. How can I iterate over this list in a JSP page?

This is what I have, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<select id="users">
   <c:forEach var="userName" items="${userNames}">
      <option>${userName}<option/>
   </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Do I need to add a tag import to be able to use elements in tag c?

Comment: *"but it doesn't seem to work:"* you should elaborate the problem in developer's perspective, not in enduser's perspective. What exactly happens instead? Any errors/exceptions? What do you see in the JSP-generated HTML output when you do rightclick and View Source in browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

The c:forEach tag is in the core JSTL library.  If you don't already, you'll also need the jstl.jar in your build path.